# Sharpe Maximization under Quadratic Constraints

Tags: optimization, portfolio-optimization, convexity, markowitz

When doing Sharpe optimization

$$
\max_x \frac{\mu^T x}{\sqrt{x^T Q x}}
$$

there is a common trick ([section 5.2](http://www.ie.bilkent.edu.tr/~mustafap/courses/OIF.pdf)) used to put the problem in convex form.  You add a variable $\kappa$ such that $x = y/\kappa$ choose $\kappa$ s.t. $\mu^T y=1$.  Changing the problem to the simple convex problem

$$
\min_{y,\kappa} y^T Q y \; \text{where} \; \mu^T y = 1, \kappa > 0
$$

which is easy to solve.

Unfortunately, my problem also has a second-order constraint that becomes non-convex in $(y,\kappa)$
$$
x^T P x \leq \sigma^2 \implies y^T P y \leq \kappa^2 \sigma^2
$$

Is there a trick to keep this problem convex and allow the use of second-order cone programming algorithms?

Comment: The KKT theorem can still be applied, as it does not have to have linear inequality constraint.

Comment: Can you expand?  I read some about the KKT theorem but I'm not sure how this helps me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic solution. However, the KKT conditions are of the forms
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
Qy + \lambda_1 \mu +\lambda_2 Py = 0,\\
\mu^T y = 1,\\
y^TPy \leq k^2 \sigma^2,\\
\lambda_2 \big( y^TPy - k^2 \sigma^2\big) = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Here, the condition $$\lambda_2 \big( y^TPy - k^2 \sigma^2\big) = 0 $$ means that two cases need to considered, that is, the one on the boundary $y^TPy = k^2 \sigma^2$ and the one inside the domain $y^TPy < k^2 \sigma^2.$

On the boundary, it is the standard Lagrange problem with conditions
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
Qy + \lambda_1 \mu +\lambda_2 Py = 0,\\
\mu^T y = 1,\\
y^TPy = k^2 \sigma^2.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Inside the domain, the constraints are
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
Qy + \lambda_1 \mu  = 0,\\
\mu^T y = 1,\\
y^TPy < k^2 \sigma^2.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The final solution $(y^T, k)$ is the one so that the global overall minimum is reached.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting.  This looks close but I'm still confused on how the quadratic form was converted to a linear form here $Qy$ by adding $\lambda_1$?  Do you have a reference?  Also, this final problem is still not convex, correct?  What sort of numerical solver could be used in this case?

Comment: @rhaskett: The form $Qy$ is the vector derivative $\frac{\partial y^T Qy}{\partial y}$. The final problem is actually easier: you only need to find a solution from the linear system and then check whether it satisfies the inequality -- it does not have to be a convex problem.

Comment: @Gordan This is really interesting.  You mention linear inequality constraints as an issue earlier.  Does that mean this doesn't work if say an additional $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ ($0 \leq y_i \leq \kappa$) constraint is imposed?

Comment: @rhaskett, See Section 2.2 of this lecture notes http://homes.soic.indiana.edu/classes/spring2012/csci/b553-hauserk/constrained_optimization.pdf may be helpful.