# Maximum Sharpe ratio portfolio - derivation

Tags: programming, sharpe-ratio

I want mathematical derivation of how to construct maximum Sharpe ratio portfolio. Any resources with mathematical derivation (if its implemented in Python, that will be great) will be useful

Comment: The theory is presented in the question here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39594/maximize-sharpe-ratio-in-portfolio-optimization . The answer contains MATLAB code, *but it has not been tested*.